# How to read file in C from a folder

Tags: c

I have a file called 'myfile.txt" in my desktop folder and I want to read this file. But I am getting the following error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I am using Ubuntu. I store c code in the Desktop folder.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char ch, array[50];
    int  j = 0;
    fp = fopen("c:\\Desktop\\myfile.txt","r");
    while(ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF) {
                array[j++]=ch;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("%c\n", array[0]);
}
```

Comment: *"I have Ubuntu machine"* and then `fopen("c:\\Desktop\\myfile.txt","r");` Is there really ``c:\`` in ubuntu ?

Comment: @Cid Was just about to ask the same thing

Comment: add a check `if (fp==NULL)` before accessing it...

Comment: You should never read from a file unless you verified that you didn't get a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: After the loop, add `array[j]='\0';` so it becomes a null terminated string that you can print with `%s`.

Comment: That is generally `/home/you/Desktop` where `you` is your Linux username. (but the location of the `Desktop` file can be desktop dependent. So open an xterm and check, e.g. `cd` then `ls -al Desktop`. If you get File Not Found, consider asking on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: You're getting segmentation error because file `"c:\\Desktop\\myfile.txt"` doesn't look like it specifies a valid path for any Linux system. (the file doesn't exist.)

Comment: You can use a *relative* path to access the file. For example if it's in the very same folder, just user `"myfile.txt"` or even `"./myfile.txt"`. But first add all the error checking like suggested in the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. The most important is your while condition.

`ch=fgetc(fp)!=EOF` is the same as `ch=(fgetc(fp)!=EOF)`. What you want is `(ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF`.

Also, `ch` should be declared as an `int`. Otherwise the check for EOF will not work properly.

Another thing is that you don't do any error checking. You should do something like this:

```
fp=fopen("c:\\Desktop\\myfile.txt","r");
if(!fp) { 
    /* Handle error */ 
}
```

Comment: Maybe add `perror("c:\\Desktop\\myfile.txt");` to the handle error block?

Comment: @pmg Yes, that's an option.

Comment: @pmg `perror("c:\\Desktop\\myfile.txt");` is a bad proposal. It would need to copy the path literally to a second line. A better choice is to define the name with either (a) a pointer to the path string, (b) a char array holding the path string, or (c) a `#define` a macro with the string. The latter would compile the string two times, but you have it only once in the source code. Use [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @harper if `fopen()` didn't use a string literal in the first place, I'd have DRY'd :)

Comment: This is getting a bit out of hand. I only wanted to show that the error should be handled in some way. Exactly how is up to OP. :)

Comment: @pmg The repeated string comes in with your "Maybe add...".